# Basic code to Delphi

Tags: delphi, openoffice.org, variant, basic

I'm struggling with the following:

The goal is to parametrize an automation server for openoffice and I'm programming in Delphi.

The piece of basic code I want to translate into Delphi code is:

```
Dim aProps(1) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
aProps(0).Name = "FilterName"
aProps(0).Value = "Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)"
aProps(1).Name = "FilterOptions"
aProps(1).Value = sFilterOptions
```

My attempt in Delphi looks like

```
type TPrmRecord = packed Record  
                    Name : String;  
                    Value : String;  
                  End;

Var
  ooParams:Variant;
  MyData : TPrmRecord;
Begin
  ooParams:= VarArrayCreate([0, 1], varVariant);

  MyData.Name  := 'FilterName';
  MyData.Value := 'Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)';
  ooParams[0]  := MyData; 

  MyData.Name  := 'FilterOptions';
  MyData.Value := '59/44,34,ANSI,1,';
  ooParams[1]  := MyData;
End;
```

This is not working does anyone have a suggestion how to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TPrmRecord` type is not what OO.org expects. You should not try to write your own types, but use those that OO.org exposes.

There is an LPGL-licensed toolbox for Delphi: [Delphi OOo](http://www.ooomacros.org/dev.php#133853). In it you will find a unit OOoTools.pas, which exports a function `CreateUnoStruct()`. Use this and pass  `'com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue'` as the name of the struct. You will get a `Variant` (or an array of those, depending on the other parameter value) back that you can use instead of `TPrmRecord` (something like the following, untested):

```
var
  Params: Variant;
begin
  Params := CreateUnoStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue', 1);

  Params[0].Name  := 'FilterName';
  Params[0].Value := 'Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)';

  Params[1].Name  := 'FilterOptions';
  Params[1].Value := '59/44,34,ANSI,1,';
end;
```

Comment: Hello mghie,
Thank you very much for this answer, could you please be more specific of how to use this function in my case?
Thanks Ad

Comment: Hello mghie that did the trick!
I use this to open a CSV file into openoffice calc.

Thank you very much for your time! Kind regards Ad.

Comment: This is the result I added this in the OOo toolbox
It opens a CSV file into calc:

function OpenCSVSheet(Filename : String) : Variant;
var
    ooParams: Variant;
    vTest   : Variant;

Begin
  vTest:=  OpenOffice.CreateInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');

  ooParams := CreateUnoStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue', 1);

  ooParams[0].Name  := 'FilterName';
  ooParams[0].Value := 'Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)';

  ooParams[1].Name  := 'FilterOptions';
  ooParams[1].Value := '59/44,34,ANSI,1,';

  result := vTest.LoadComponentFromURL(FileName2URL(FileName), '_blank', 0, ooParams);
End;

Comment: To be complete this is the FileName2URL routine:
function FileName2URL(FileName: string): string;
begin
  result:= '';
  if LowerCase(copy(FileName,1,8))<>'file:///' then
    result:= 'file:///';
  result:= result + StringReplace(FileName, '\', '/', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
end;

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you're missing the creation of the COM class, which would be the equivalent of the `New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue` line in your code.

I suspect you need to import the type library into Delphi which would give you the objects, properties and methods you need to emulate the Basic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is straight Delphi code without using Delphi OOo:

```
uses comobj;

var
  OO_ServiceManager: OleVariant;
  FileParams: OleVariant;

begin
  OO_ServiceManager := CreateOleObject ('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
  FileParams := VarArrayCreate([0, 1], varVariant);
  FileParams[0] := OO_ServiceManager.Bridge_GetStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue');
  FileParams[0].Name := 'FilterName';
  FileParams[0].Value := 'Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)';
  FileParams[1] := OO_ServiceManager.Bridge_GetStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue');
  FileParams[1].Name := 'FilterOptions';
  FileParams[1].Value := '59/44,34,ANSI,1,';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this Thread in the german Delphi-PRAXiS forums](http://www.delphipraxis.net/topic7569,0,asc,0.html&highlight=openoffice). There is a whole delphi Unit posted doing some OOo automation.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
var
ooParams:array[0..1] of TPrmRecord;
```

delphi uses strict type-casting, so this is causing an assignment error.